# How to detect browsers language and check the language is spanish or english?

Tags: php

in my website i have two options one is english and one is spanish.

for `english=en-US,en;q=0.5 and for spanish=es-es, es; q = 0,5.`

I used `$lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];`

now i want to check the condition and chage the logo of my websites.but every time its gives me bad result.how can i do that.anyhelp will be appricated.

Comment: Similarly anwser, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770616/1172872

Comment: i know you only whole day find the duplicate question.my aim is to get the answer not to ask duplicate question.anyway thanks.@ sk8terboi87

Answer (score 2):

you could do:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "es":   //spanish
        include("logo_es.php");
        break;
    case "en":  //english and any other language
    default:
        //for english and default
        include("logo.php");
        break;
}
```

Comment: its only give me for english when i transfer in spanish its cant give me proper result