# How identify the browser language of the visitor in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following problem using WordPress:

When the theme is loading I have to save in a variable (or something like it) the browser language of the visitor.

Can I do something like it?

Comment: Have a look at this previous SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php

Comment: ok, I think that this is perfect for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

Means you want Language Traslator or anything else.
You can used Google trasalator plugion or WPML is also best plugion for language traslator.

Comment: no I have to load different main menu based on the user language, not the content

Comment: So for that then WPML  Plugion for wordpress is Best One.