# Change language selection text based on browser language?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a basic dropdown menu where the user is able to select the language the website should appear in. My problem is not everyone understands "Select Language". So I was trying to find a method that allows to detect the language of the browser and serve an appropiate text accordingly.

For example if:

User Agent is in English

then:

"Select Language"

How do I do this with PHP or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

On the server side in PHP, use the Accept-Language header to determine the browser's configured language. Details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php).