# How to write this if statement(s) shorter way

Tags: php, coding-style

Is it possible to write this shorter? I can't make changes to accept_lang method, and it always returns a boolean.

```
if ($ci->agent->accept_lang('en-US') OR $ci->agent->accept_lang('en-GB') OR $ci->agent->accept_lang('en-au'))
```

Comment: no you cant, without altering the method

Comment: Are you trying to avoid calling the method 3 times, or do you just want less characters on that line?

Comment: Less characters, @Flosculus

Comment: @singhakash I'm aware how to check if something is in array, I'm just curious if it is possible to write it shorter if I have to use this frameworks built-in method.

Comment: Are you willing to have another function to make this shorter?

Comment: Maybe try something like this: `$arr = array("en", "de");
 array_walk($arr, array($ci, "agent")); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not shorter, but a simple loop could help. 
Add the most common regions first to reduce the number of checks and the break to stop checking if you find one.

```
<?php
foreach(array('en-US','en-GB','en-au') as $lang) {if($ci->agent->accept_lang($lang)){stuff();break;}}
?>
```

or broken out:

```
<?php
foreach(array('en-US','en-GB','en-au') as $lang) {
  if($ci->agent->accept_lang($lang)){
    stuff(); // or whatever else you need, or set a $flag = true
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Cheers, maybe not the most efficient way, but this is something I was thinking about, but couldn't think of myself.

Answer (score 0):

How about use followings? It's copy from

[Detect Browser Language in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php)

why dont you keep it simple and clean

```
<?php
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "fr":
        //echo "PAGE FR";
        include("index_fr.php");//include check session FR
        break;
    case "it":
        //echo "PAGE IT";
        include("index_it.php");
        break;
    case "en":
        //echo "PAGE EN";
        include("index_en.php");
        break;        
    default:
        //echo "PAGE EN - Setting Default";
        include("index_en.php");//include EN in all other cases of different lang detection
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your are looking for true within an array of results, using `in_array` i.c.w. `array_map` you can construct the following one-liner;

```
if (in_array(true, array_map(array($ci, "accept_lang"), array("en-US", "en-GB", "en-au"))))
```

Broken out a bit to show more clearly what is happening;

```
$langAccept = array_map(array($ci, "accept_lang"), array("en-US", "en-GB", "en-au"));
if (in_array(true, $langAccept)) {
    // ...
}
```