# Location Based Redirect

Tags: php, geolocation

I am working on a personal website and I am trying to implement a system that redirects a user before he reaches the website to the same version of the website but in the user's appropriate language.

I don't have shell access, I only have access to DirectAdmin.. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: title says location, text says language - not the same thing so which do you want ?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770616/4633718) might help you, a simple and clean solution.

Comment: You can use PHP's GeoIP extension to locate a user from their IP address, but this isn't always reliable. Alternatively, you could check the `Accept-Language:` header and see which language they'd prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage to solve the problem with browser language. 
Put in header:

```
    var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;

    if (language != "pt-pt") {
        window.location.href = "www.yoursite.en";
    }
```