# PHP Language Detection Without Redirecting Users to Another Page

Tags: php

We have a very simple and lightweight mobile lander that is receiving tons of traffic from all over the world...so we want our site to detect where they are from and show our page in their local language without redirecting them to another page )index-fr.php for instance.

What's the best way to do it in PHP without sacrificing loading speed?

Much thanks!

Comment: check on the ip adress and make a database table that holds ip adress ranges with country relations

Comment: http://php.net/setlocale

Comment: This has been answered here :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770616/541591

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Browser Language in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php)