# How to localize a language and redirect the user to a specific url with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a website  in two languages with CodeIgniter: 
English (en) and 
German (de).

The default page is: www.mysite.com

The url for en is: **www.mysite.com/en/**
The url for de is **www.mysite.com/de/**

Now I would like to redirect the user according to his/her device language.
I know, the script below it's not the right way.

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch($lang){
case 'en':
return redirect(site_url('en/'));
break;
case 'de';
return redirect(site_url('de/'));
break;
default:
return redirect(site_url('en/'));
}
```

How can I exactly manage it?

Comment: Why don't you just redirect(site_url($lang)) ? EDIT: Nevermind, you need a default of english if it is not one of the two.  You would need to swtich Lang both ways

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect Browser Language in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php)

Comment: remove return from redirect and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there is syntax error in your code at case 'de';

It would be case 'de':

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch($lang){
case 'en':
redirect(site_url('en/'));
break;
case 'de':
redirect(site_url('de/'));
break;
default:
redirect(site_url('en/'));
}
```

And make sure you have load url helper

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Also remove return from redirect