# How to determine default language for multi lingual countries

Tags: c#, localization

I'd like my website (c#) to detect visitor's country and present the website in their local language. This is straight forward for the most part but I've run into problems for the following countries:

- Canada
- Switzerland
- Taiwan

All of which have at least two languages being spoken. 
I was wondering if there are ways to detect the language preference for visitors from these countries. 
I've thought of a couple of things:

1. Region based detection, pinpoint which region of the country are they from by capturing IP.
2. Detect the visitor's OS language and replicate that.

If you have other ideas I'd greatly appreciate it. How does other website do this?

Comment: What language / framework are you using?

Comment: You could just make links for each language version of the page and let the user decide which they prefer.

Comment: Tim, I'm using C#.
Robert, that feature already exists. I'd like to make it automatic.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from framework and language (of programming) that you use.

For example in pure `PHP` there is variable `$_SERVER` with property `'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'`, example of usage in the link below:

> [Detect Browser Language in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770513/detect-browser-language-in-php)

In Symphony you can configure translator setting parameter as `'%locale%'`.

> http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/i18n.html

A lot of information about `IP` and `OS` there are in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I'm using c# but I like the idea of browser language detection.