# Set dynamic PHP page title using a lang file

Tags: php

I'm trying to set a page title dynamically using PHP, where it pulls the name of the page from a lang file, however I can't get the syntax quite right.

Example:

lang.en.php

```
<?php $lang['TITLE_INDEX'] = 'My Index Page'; ?>
```

header.php

```
<?php include 'lang.en.php' ?><title><?php echo $pagetitle ?></title>
```

index.php

```
<?php $pagetitle = $lang['TITLE_INDEX']; include 'header.php' ?>
```

It pulls the language through a common file which works out which lang to use (en,de etc), however I cann't get the $pagetitle var to output the $lang.

Comment: The include should come before the output.

Comment: You need to set the variable before you include the header.php. Otherwise it would not yet exist.

Comment: You missed a few `;`. 2 after `include` and another one after the `echo`

Comment: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are setting the variable $pagetitle after the include. Try this:

```
<?php include 'lang.en.php'; $pagetitle = $lang['TITLE_INDEX']; include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've given that a go and it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to like setting $pagetitle as another $var ($pagetitle = $lang['TITLE_INDEX'];)

Comment: Then you may have another issue. But my answer should point you in the right direction. I am confused as to why it was voted down.

Comment: It was downvoted because it is wrong. You have to do the include before you can utilize the variables in the included file. You're missing the include of the language file.

Comment: Hi Jay, that was meant to point him in the right direction. He got back to me by saying that it didn't work. Like other answers, I follow back with the user in answering further questions to arrive at the right answer. Respectfully, my answer was immediately down voted without the chance of an update or anything else.

Comment: Respectfully it was wrong right out of the gate. We should strive to make our answers as right as possible without having to await clarification before editing.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I am still learning how to use Stackoverflow effectively. I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

the order of the includes is important. PHP will replace the include by the actual code exactly where the include is. Don't forget to include your lang file too, or the value will not be set:

index.php

```
<?php
include 'lang.en.php';
$pagetitle = $lang['TITLE_INDEX'];
include 'header.php';
?>
```

note: of course, you will replace the `en` in your lang import by your locale dynamically

Comment: Thanks, I've give that a go - it seems '$pagetitle = $lang['TITLE_INDEX'];' does not work

Comment: do you have an error displayed somehow? you might need to set $lang as an array first, before adding a row, with `$lang = array();` in lang.en.php

Comment: No error, it just returns blank. The lang.en.php file is an array, and it works if I <?php echo $lang['TITLE_INDEX']; ?>, just not when trying to set it as a $var

Comment: you get a blank title or a whole blank page? in the second case, it might be an error but that your configuration does not allow to show. does adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the very beginning of the code does something? (at the beginning means before any include)

Comment: It just returns a blank title, the rest works, unfortunately no errors. It just seems that you can't do $var = $var1

Comment: If you echo $lang['TITLE_INDEX'] inside of header.php, do you get the title? If you do the same within the index.php, do you get the title?

Comment: from the clues i have, there are few things i can figure to go wrong, except a typo that was not copied here, or a scope problem (if you do the import in a function, or a framework file that is included in a function). If the latter, you can try to set the vars as `global`. The rest is simple, it should work

Comment: If I echo it within header.php or index.php it returns fine, just not if setting it as a var

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to include lang.en.php. The basic file structure should look like this:

**lang.en.php:**

```
$lang = [];
$lang['TITLE_INDEX'] = 'My Index Page';
```

**header.php:**

```
$usedLang = "en";
include_once("lang.$usedLang.php");
```

**index.php:**

```
include_once("header.php");

echo $pagetitle;
```

Take a look here, to find the default language https://stackoverflow.com/a/30300728/1152471