# PHP: list() giving unused local variable error in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using the answer found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749660 in order to sort the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` array by the most preferred language.

In that answer (which is working great by the way), one line is:

`list($a, $b) = explode('-', $match[1]) + array('', '');`

Within PhpStorm, I get the following error for that line:

"Unused local variable $b: The value of the variable is overwritten immediately".

I'm a little confused as to what this line is doing exactly, so I don't know if I should just keep it the same, or if I should modify it to:

`list($a) = explode('-', $match[1]) + array('', '');`

... which also seems to be working fine.

Should it be changed?

Comment: I think you have incorrect expectations to what `explode() + array()` does.

Comment: @Havenard I clearly stated that I am using an answer given in another question and I am unsure as to what that line is doing. That's basically what I'm asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't join arrays with the arithmetic operator `+`. Basically you are telling PHP to convert the arrays to scalar types and then sum them, which yields you a number (probably arrays evaluate to 1 if it has elements and 0 if it doesn't).

The result is that effectively you are doing something like:

```
list($a, $b) = 2;
```

And the conclusion PHP reaches is that you haven't specified enough elements to define all the variables in the list.

To join two arrays together, use `array_merge()`.

```
list($a, $b) = array_merge(explode('-', $match[1]), array('', ''));
```

Comment: `+` is also the [**Union** array operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php). I don't normally use it because I can never remember what rules it follows, but it's indeed overloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The wording is confusing because it's a full explanation for an inspection that covers two situations and the initial tooltip only displays the first line, which happens to describe the *other* situation. If you hit <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> you can read the complete text, which kind of makes more sense (emphasis mine):

> Unused local variable 'b'. The value of the variable is overwritten
>   immediately. less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> Inspection info: A variable is considered unused in the following
>   cases:
>
> - **The value of the variable is not used anywhere** or is overwritten immediately.
> - The reference stored in the variable is not used anywhere or is overwritten immediately.

That's exactly what happens here:

```
list($a, $b) = …
```

`$a` is used later but `$b` is not. Since `$b` is never used, this works as well:

```
list($a) = explode('-', $match[1]) + array('', '');
```

(Remember these inspections are hints to prevent potential bugs, not necessarily errors.)